# CSS: position:sticky child not working in parent having property: flex-direction: column-reverse;

Tags: html, css

Best community,

I have a chat app where the messages are in a parent holding the css prop: flex-direction: column-reverse;
This way the parent div is always scrolled to the bottom.

However I want to stick the dates on top whan passing them by, but this doesn't seem to work with the flex-direction: column-reverse; property, does anyone know a hack to get this working (I prefer not using javascript jquery exemple: ($(".messages").scrollTop($(".messages")[0].scrollHeight);) in order to scroll to the bottom of the div) but rather see a solution in css.

working exemple without property column-reversed:

```css
.messages
{
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  
}

.messages .message 
{
    display: flex;
    margin: 10px;
    padding:10px;
    min-height: max-content;
    align-items: flex-end;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    background:#eee;
}

.messages .message.me
{
  justify-content:flex-end;
}

.messages .date-devider {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: #FF9800;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 900;
    position: sticky;
    border-radius: 2px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 2;
```

```html
<div class="messages">

  <div class="message me">
  1st message 
  </div>

  <div class="message he">
  2nd message
  </div>

  <div class="message me">
  3st message 
  </div>

  <div class="date-devider">15 jan 2019 (stick on top)</div>

  <div class="message he">
  4nd message
  </div>

  <div class="message me">
  5st message 
  </div>

  <div class="message he">
  6nd message
  </div>

  <div class="message he">
  7nd message
  </div>

  <div class="message me">
  8st message 
  </div>
  <div class="date-devider">15 jan 2019 (inline until scroll reaches top)</div>

  <div class="message he">
  9nd message
  </div>
</div>
```

Exemple not working with parent column property reversed:

```css
.messages
{
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  
}

.messages .message 
{
    display: flex;
    margin: 10px;
    padding:10px;
    min-height: max-content;
    align-items: flex-end;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    background:#eee;
}

.messages .message.me
{
  justify-content:flex-end;
}

.messages .date-devider {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: #FF9800;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 900;
    position: sticky;
    border-radius: 2px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 2;
```

```html
<div class="messages">

  <div class="message me">
  1st message 
  </div>

  <div class="message he">
  2nd message
  </div>

  <div class="message me">
  3st message 
  </div>

  <div class="date-devider">15 jan 2019 (stick on top)</div>

  <div class="message he">
  4nd message
  </div>

  <div class="message me">
  5st message 
  </div>

  <div class="message he">
  6nd message
  </div>

  <div class="message he">
  7nd message
  </div>

  <div class="message me">
  8st message 
  </div>
  <div class="date-devider">15 jan 2019 (inline until scroll reaches top)</div>

  <div class="message he">
  9nd message
  </div>
</div>
```